# cx_freeze: compile a python script

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm trying to compile a Python script with cx_freeze and it's working 100%

but it's have alot of files (*.so) mean when I'm trying to compile :

```
test.py
```

It's have files like this : test, socket.so, zope.interface.so and so on

Can I collect all of (*.so) in a zipfile and let just test file out ?

like this :

```
library.zip, test
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear to what you really want to achieve, but I suggest to read the manual  FAQ, it probably is the answer: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables

Comment: @deets Hi, I mean Can I collect all (*.so) files and set it in zipfile and keep run file out !

Comment: "keep run file out" is not a sentence that I understand. And you still not say *why* you want this. In general though, you can't just arbitrarily zip around things and hope they will work. Have you read the manual of cx-freeze?

Comment: @deets Yes, I don't find any thing

Comment: @deets "Keep run file out", Such as we make "test.py" script and we set a zip library to import Script from it, and here I wan't to set "test" it's name like this because I'm using linux and "test" it's operating file and library "library.zip"

Comment: The link in @deets first comment is the best answer to this. cx_Freeze does not include any way to bundle all the libraries into one file. There are some extra tools you can use that make a self-extracting zip file that will unpack itself and then run your code.